# How can I use this 2 Fonts in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.myfont.de/fonts/infos/5512-Bar-Code-39-lesbar.html

How can I use this Fonts in my HTML5 Webpage?

```
.ft14{font: 20pt 'code39';line-height: 15px;}
```

Doesnt work..

Answer (score 1):

You have to fist download the font and upload it somewhere. Then use CSS3 @font-face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font_Name';
  font-style: fontstyle;
  font-weight: Font-weight;
  src: local('Font_Name'), local('Font_Name'), url(Font.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: How can I do this for code39?

Answer (score 0):

To use a font like that you first need to import it in your CSS file. Assuming you've placed your stylesheet in `src/css` and code39.ttf (which you can download from the page you've linked to) in `src/font`, just add this to your stylesheet.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: code39;
    src: url(../font/code39.ttf);
}
```

If you've done this, the CSS code in your question should work. Good luck!